# Checking Dart SDK version... << was unexpected at this time. in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

`The Flutter Daemon failed to start.`

What is this error? even when I'm running flutter doctor its showing
`Checking Dart SDK version...<< was unexpected at this time.`
Its working well and good yesterday. Turing on my device again and open my flutter project in Vs code/Andriod studio showing this error unexpectedly

```
 [2:45:48 pm] [General] [Info] Searching for SDKs...
[2:45:48 pm] [General] [Info] Environment PATH:
[2:45:48 pm] [General] [Info]     C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-11.0.10.9-hotspot\bin
[2:45:48 pm] [General] [Info]     C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath
[2:45:48 pm] [General] [Info]     C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\
[2:45:48 pm] [General] [Info]     C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\
[2:45:48 pm] [General] [Info]     C:\WINDOWS\system32
[2:45:48 pm] [General] [Info]     C:\WINDOWS
[2:45:48 pm] [General] [Info]     C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem
[2:45:48 pm] [General] [Info]     C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
[2:45:48 pm] [General] [Info]     C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL
```

Comment: Does `dart --version` work?

Comment: No, same thing `Checking Dart SDK version...<< was unexpected at this time`

Comment: should I reinstall the flutter again? is there any other way to solve this?

Comment: Maybe this will help https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/89687 A reinstall could be worth a try too.

Comment: flutter reinstall worked for me....!!

Comment: Solution that worked for me (for Windows): 1) Run `git reset --hard` in C:\flutter, 2) `flutter upgrade`

Answer (score 3):

Flutter reinstalled worked for me..

- delete flutter folder in C directroy.
- make a src folder in C: directory.
- GoTo cmd and install flutter from official flutter github repo `C:\src>git clone https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git -b stable`
- https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows
- run flutter doctor
- set env path.

DONE